# The ship "set sail" or the ship "sets sail"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs, past-vs-present, verb-phrases

In this sentence:

> The ship (**set**/**sets**) sail for the city of New York on the fifth of April.

Should we use "*set*" or "*sets*"?

- Note that it is *not* known if the "fifth of April" is in the past or the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the right tense, you **have to** know whether the event is taking place in the past or the future. In this case, **set** is the past tense, and **sets** is the present (or can be—and often is—used for future). But you can't get the right tense without knowing what you're describing.